# Xamarin with Fellow-oak DICOM doesn't not create DicomNative.dll in bin folder

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, dicom, fo-dicom

I have created on Windows 8.1 Xamarin Project (Shared Project, Xamarin.Android & Xamarin.iOS ) which is simple dicom image viewer.

We are using Fellow-oak Dicom installed via nuget-packages.

In Shared Project there is method responsible for loading new dicom image by using  DicomImage object from **Fellow-oak DICOM**.

```
foreach(string file_name in files)
        {
            try
            {

                dicom_file = DicomFile.Open(file_name);
                DicomImage dcmimg = new DicomImage(file_name);

                file_list.Add(dcmimg);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Function which is responsible for loading DicomImage is called from Xamarin.Android 
After deploying app on mobile and trying to load dcm image the crash occurs and following error is displayed: 
**“No codec registered for tranfer syntax: JPEG 2000 Image Compression”**

After research I found out what is probably the source of the issue: **missing DicomNative dll which should be created after building project but it doesn’t**.  So on the internet there were saying about setting target platform to either x64 or x86 but it didn’t help. 
I have set target platform of all projects in solution to x64 then I tried with x86.

Is there any other way to force including this dll ( I don't know from where I can download physically this lacking codec) or maybe some other fix for this problem ?

Comment: Have you checked the properties of the DLL in your solution explorer - make sure the "Copy Local" option is set to true. Also, and I don't know anything of the libraries you're using, some cases the DLL's are part of an installation you perform on the host machine and not specific to the bin of your project.

Comment: @Darren, This DLL is not present in Solution Explorer, I guess it's created during building a project.

Comment: If you don't have code in your solution that forms this dll then it's likely the dll that was added to your system by an installation. That same installation will need to be done on your host system or you need to have another process to copy this across, such as post-build https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833213(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I guess that Fellow-oak DICOM should form this library or at least assign it to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In versions 2.0.x of *fo-dicom* for Xamarin iOS and Android, compressed codecs are not supported at all.

In version 3.0, which is currently under Beta, for *Xamarin* iOS and Android there is limited support for JPEG 8-bit baseline and progressive codecs and JPEG2000 8-bit (monochrome and RGB).

The comprehensive support, including 12- and 16-bit monochrome images, JPEG Lossless and JPEG-LS near lossless and lossless, is only available on .NET Framework and the *Universal Windows Platform*, UWP. The issue with the missing *Dicom.Native* DLL is only related to .NET Framework.

The .NET Framework and UWP implementations are using more complete C/C++ class libraries for codec support, whereas the *Xamarin* implementations are currently making use of the C# based managed code class libraries [LibJpeg.NET](http://bitmiracle.com/libjpeg/) and [CSJ2K](https://github.com/cureos/csj2k) which are considerably more limited in a DICOM context.